# Fail to perform a new query in Visual Studio 2015 against a database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio, localdb

I have successfully created a sample server-based database in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with settings in Tools>Options>Data Tools>Data Connection under SQL Server Instance Name set to 'SQLEXPRESS'. However, upon performing a new query against the database, it displays this error:

> Msq 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name 'Recipe'.

My query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM Recipe
```

My database is named as "Cookbook" with tables `Recipe, Ingredient, RecipeIngredient.`

When initiating a query, in the Available Databases drop-down menu, the database I have created isn't listed. Is that possible? For Visual Studio to have created a database but not include it in the Available Databases menu?

But creating a database in SQL Server Management Studio is ok. It's in the Available Databases list.

My assumption is that Visual Studio has created a local database instead of a service-based one.

Anyway I am following this guy's tutorial
youtube.com/watch?v=L1m1Znj9dZA (2:28 )
 and encountered this error. Please enlighten me. :)

Comment: Link to the tutorial?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1m1Znj9dZA  2:28

Answer (score 0):

Try building/rebuilding your project, helps most of the times.